# What is advantage of using Appium over AI automation tools like Testproject, TestSigma?

Tags: mobile, automation, cloud, appium

I need to decide a framework for mobile automation, I believe appium is better than AI based automation tools, I need to know the advantages of using appium over AI based automation tools.

Comment: would love to hear different thoughts on this